# Ошибка при запуске JAVA приложения

Tags: java

Пытаюсь запустить minecraft сервер на Debian 8, но при запуске возникает ошибка: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/UJ6KtxE5).

До этого полгода работало все нормально. Пробовал переустанавливать джаву, но это не помогло. Я так понимаю это проблемы с оперативной памятью на машине?

Comment: [Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28982396/312041)

Comment: тоже самое, только дамп появился в той же директории https://pastebin.com/raw/gfaib8xP

Comment: Проблема точно не в оперативке (недостаточности или утечке). Пробовали перезапускать систему? Попробуйте обновить 8ю джаву до последнего патча. Похоже на баг в GC. Как вариант - поменять GC